# GDrive google-api-php-client- Do not authenticate

Tags: google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I've tried the **`URL`** below but does not go to the Google Request Permission page and so do not fetch the code.

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://Adhym.staging.abc.com/wp-content/plugins/SFMarketo/google-api-php-client/gDrive_access/roi_results_upload.php&client_id=xxx&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive&access_type=offline&approval_prompt=auto
```

But if the return **`URL`** is changed to the localhost - as below - it works fine as expected.

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost:2345/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/SFMarketo/google-api-php-client/gDrive_access/roi_results_upload.php&client_id=xxx&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive&access_type=offline&approval_prompt=auto
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause of the issue There was a file access permission in the Staging server.

Giving the required permission in the staging server to the folder location where the token file (received from Google Request permission page) resides solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

On my personal experience, I had the same problem some time ago and I found out I was not including the URL in the "Authorized redirect URIs" section of my project credentials.

Please go to console.developers.google.com, select your project, go to credentials, select the client ID and you will see a screen similar to this one
[Credentials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plcpj.png)

Reference: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the correct [ClientID](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project) for your website. One way to check is create a client ID without any restriction for ***Authorized JavaScript origins*** and ***Authorized redirect URIs*** or both. You may have used a ClientID that only localhost is authorized to call the request.

> In the Authorized JavaScript origins field, enter the origin for your app. You can enter multiple origins to allow for your app to run on different protocols, domains, or subdomains. You cannot use wildcards. In the example below, the second URL could be a production URL.

```
http://localhost:8080
https://myproductionurl.example.com
```

Also, it you help you to log the errors or open the [DevTool](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) to efficiently track down layout issues, set JavaScript breakpoints, and get insights for code optimization.

Hope this helps!